# Notation for orbital coefficient matrix in RHF vs UHF

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, electronic-configuration

My question stems from Table 1 of this paper:

"Generalized Hartree–Fock Description of Molecular Dissociation, by
Carlos A. Jiménez-Hoyos, Thomas M. Henderson, and Gustavo E. Scuseria"
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ct200345a

In particular, I am confused about the notation for the subscript of the elements in the orbital coefficient matrix. For a real RHF ansatz for the two-electron/two-orbital system, for example, we should have

\begin{gather}
  |\psi\rangle
  = C_{11}^{\sigma\sigma}|\phi_1\alpha,\,
    \phi_1\beta\rangle + C_{22}^{\sigma\sigma}|\phi_2\alpha,\,
    \phi_2\beta\rangle, 
\end{gather}
(where I have changed notation slightly from the original paper by putting the sigma's in the superscript) while for a real UHF, we have
\begin{gather}
  |\psi\rangle
  = C_{11}^{\sigma\sigma}|\phi_1\alpha,\,
    \phi_1\beta\rangle + C_{22}^{\sigma'\sigma'}|\phi_2\alpha,\,
    \phi_2\beta\rangle,
\end{gather}
where the $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are spatial orbitals and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the spin orbitals.

Does the superscript $\sigma\sigma$ vs $\sigma'\sigma'$ signify the variational coefficients? For example, does $C_{11}^{\sigma\sigma}$ correspond to a variation of the alpha and beta spin coefficients with the same variational parameter, while a term say $C_{12}^{\sigma\sigma'}$ corresponds to varying alpha and beta with different parameters? I don't believe this notation is explained in the paper.

I also find similar notation [here (unfortunately, no online pdf)](https://books.google.com/books?id=8QiR8lCX_qcC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=%22invariant%20one-body%20operator%22&source=bl&ots=NM7D1_BTdM&sig=ACfU3U1tLVcvLAjqjMLMXBh4DrshwTbqug&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL39mg09X1AhXsct8KHb1QBRwQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22invariant%20one-body%20operator%22&f=false). Now, RHF, UHF, GHF, etc. are defined by the matrix-structure of the orbital coefficient matrix. It looks like the block-diagonal terms correspond to how we vary the spatial component in the HF ansatz with respect to the different spin sectors (correct?) Do off-diagonal terms in the orbital coefficient matrix correspond to variation of the spin sectors themselves? Is there a more accessible reference that discusses this reasoning in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are spin-blocking the canonical MO coefficients $\mathbf{C}$, in other words treating the spin orbitals as two-component spin vectors. I think this spin-structure [is easier to see](https://joshuagoings.com/assets/ghf.pdf) [with one-body operators](https://joshuagoings.com/2014/10/14/broken-symmetries-in-hartree-fock/) like the Hamiltonian (Fock operator) or density matrix, but we can still apply the spin-blocking in this case.

Say we have an atomic spin orbital
\begin{gather}
  |\Phi\rangle 
    = |\phi\rangle|\sigma\rangle 
    = \pmatrix{\phi_\alpha\phi_\beta},
\end{gather}
where $|\phi\rangle$ is the spatial component and $|\sigma\rangle \in \{|\alpha\rangle, |\beta\rangle\}$ (spin-up and spin-down, respectively).

Then the general canonical spin orbital $|\Psi\rangle$ can be obtained from the coefficient matrix $\mathbf{C}$ as
\begin{gather}
  |\Psi\rangle 
    = \mathbf{C} |\Phi\rangle 
    = \pmatrix{
        C_{\alpha\alpha} & C_{\alpha\beta} \\ 
        C_{\beta\alpha} & C_{\beta\beta}
      }
      \pmatrix{
        \phi_\alpha \\ 
        \phi_\beta
      }.
\end{gather}

In the RHF case, $C_{\alpha\alpha} = C_{\beta\beta}$, and so
\begin{gather}
  |\Psi\rangle 
    = \mathbf{C} |\Phi\rangle 
    = \pmatrix{
        C_{\alpha\alpha} & 0 \\
        0 & C_{\alpha\alpha}
      }
      \pmatrix{
        \phi_\alpha \\
        \phi_\beta
      } 
    = C_{\alpha\alpha}
      \pmatrix{
        \phi_\alpha \\ \phi_\beta
      }, 
\end{gather}
which describes two spin-paired electrons in a single spatial orbital.

In the UHF case, $C_{\alpha\alpha} \neq C_{\beta\beta}$, and so
\begin{gather}
  |\Psi\rangle 
  = \mathbf{C} |\Phi\rangle 
  = \pmatrix{
      C_{\alpha\alpha} & 0 \\ 
      0 & C_{\beta\beta}
    }
    \pmatrix{
      \phi_\alpha \\
      \phi_\beta
    } 
    = \pmatrix{
        C_{\alpha\alpha} \phi_\alpha \\
        C_{\beta\beta}\phi_\beta
      }, 
\end{gather}
which describes two opposite spin electrons in a separate spatial orbitals.

In the GHF case, where we relax the requirement for electrons to be eigenfunctions of $\hat{S}_z$, we can write the general case as
\begin{gather}
  |\Psi\rangle 
  = \mathbf{C} |\Phi\rangle 
  = \pmatrix{
      C_{\alpha\alpha} & C_{\alpha\beta} \\
      C_{\beta\alpha} & C_{\beta\beta}
    }
    \pmatrix{
      \phi_\alpha \\
      \phi_\beta
    } 
  = \pmatrix{
      C_{\alpha\alpha} \phi_\alpha + C_{\alpha\beta} \phi_\beta\\
      C_{\beta\alpha} \phi_\alpha + C_{\beta\beta}\phi_\beta
    }.
\end{gather}
All the $C_{\sigma\sigma'}$ coefficients are independent variational parameters, subject to orthonormality constraints. Moreover, coefficients may be real or complex-valued.

Comment: Does the alpha/beta subscript on the spatial $\phi$ denote the spin orbital or the spatial orbital?

Comment: I have usually seen the different spatial orbitals denoted by A and B, as opposed to $\alpha$ or $\beta$

Comment: Alpha/beta on spatial $\phi$ denotes the spatial orbital corresponding to that particular spin block. It's not common to work with the full spin blocked matrix, since off-diagonal spin elements are generally zero, with GHF being the exception.

Comment: I believe I understand. So when writing a 2-electron Slater determinant for some GHF state, say, would it be correct to say that each element mixes the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ sectors; i.e., each element would be of the form $\psi_\nu(r,\,s)=\alpha(s)\sum_\mu c_{\nu \mu}\phi_\mu(r)+\beta(s) \sum_\mu c_{\nu \mu}'\phi_\mu(r)$? (here, the c's are the elements of your C matrices). I am looking in Szabo's QC book, but they don't seem to consider the case of constructing Slater determinants with spin orbital mixing a la GHF